# .ideavimrc file mapping Esc key

Tags: intellij-plugin, ideavim

I would like this vim mapping to work in ideavim.

```
    inoremap <S-Space> <Esc>
```

It maps <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> with <kbd>Esc</kbd> in insert mode.

Any ideas what to put in my `.ideavimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

You can put exactly this line into your ~/.ideavimrc and it will result in the expected mapping.

You can try it interactively as well by typing `:inoremap <S-Space> <Esc>`.

**Edit:** It's currently not possible. Vote for [VIM-1026](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1026) at IdeaVim's bug tracker to get updates.

Comment: I tried it and it does not map it to `Shift` `Space` but to `Space` only. Therefore in insert mode, it escapes insert mode every time we press `Space`.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this?